Is lost update possible with serializable transaction isolation?
It is often stated serializable transactions prevents all read phenomena including lost update and phantoms. But is this the case when read committed transaction (A) and serializable transaction (B) are being executing concurrently?

Transaction A begins and reads a row (shared lock is acquired for the duration of select statement)
Transaction B begins and reads a row (exclusive lock is acquired for the duration of transaction)
Transaction A updates a row (blocking until transaction B commits)
Transaction B commits (exclusive lock is freed)
Transaction A proceeds and commits (resulting in lost update)

Is the serializable semantics effective only in the group of all transactions being serializable, or am I missing something?
